# How to write in GCS using spark java in dataproc?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to use GCP to run spark application, i am using dataproc to trigger application and want to write output in Google Cloud Storage for this i have GCS connector added in my pom.xml

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
        <version>hadoop3-2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

It help's me to read CSV from GCS but when i try to write result in GCS it throws a very annoying error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /user/root/gs/2022-12-27 12:08:48 from hdfs://dm-service-metanome-m/user/root/gs/2022-12-27 12:08:48 is not a valid DFS filename.
```

Can anyone help me ?

i use the following code to write output in GCS.

```
javaRDDString.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(location+"/"+(DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).toString()));
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this, but it looks like there is a space in that filename (between `2022-12-27` and `12:08:48`). Typically spaces in filenames are not a good idea. Try removing the space character?

Comment: Can you add how are you writing the data? i.e. writer code

Comment: Hi @Faisal Khan, can you provide the sample code which you have tried?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thanks for your response mam but unfortunately my code base is too large, so i can not show you where does the output came from but at the last it store in a JavaRDD<String> object and then after code is available above here.